# How can i import a son model with relation to a father model?

Tags: import, relation, google-app-maker

i've a application with 2 Google Drive Tables (FatherM & SonM models)
and with a many to one relation

i'm able to export the data in a spreadsheet 
in the SonM model at export an extra column is created automaticaly by the export with the name of the relation (FatherM) and containing all the Keys of the fathers records

when i import the single model data Son spreadsheet i've an error :

V:1 Field names "FatherM" in the spreadsheet can't be found in the corresponding model.

yes it doesn't exist in the model but is created by the relation

how can i import SonM datas ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between "import single model" and "import all models and relations" modes that "import single model" doesn't import relations, instead it expects that all columns in your spreadsheet are fields of a model. You can try to use "import all models and relations" mode with a spreadsheet where is all other (except of SonM) spreadsheets tabs don't contain data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your answer

I’m now using the all models to import relation too.

Her are some comments. if you have any information to give me, don’t hesitate to tell me

My goal is to export all the models from a test environment in a spreadsheet, add row manually or modify, then later on I will import all the data on a prod environment

1)  I’ve exported all the data OK
2)  I’ve re imported all the data :

First remark :  if one of the spread sheet tab is empty (only one line with the title column)
 I’ve got an error at import : Cannot read property "length" from null. 0 records imported
I’ve deleted all the tabs that don’t have data, and now not any more this error

Second remark: I’ve another import message from google import
Value error at cell "V:6": Can't import association: "Invit - Event", because record key is not defined. 0 records imported
Event is my father model and Invit is my son model. (for One Event I’ve many Invitation)
About V:6 , in Invit tab V is the relation column to the Event. (it contains all the key that are link with the main _Key of the Event model, the name of this column is the name of the relation I’ve created)
The first 5 lines of this tab are the invitation I’ve made manually using the my appmaker application, (and each of these line have a _Key value on column A) the line 6 and after are invitation I’ve added manually (coming from another tool, theses are old invitations I need to import)
On line 6 and after the column A (_key) is empty
The cell value in V:6 is an Event(_Key) ant it exist. So I don’t understand the import error message from Google. (do you understand this message?)

Third remarks
I’ve jus done this test:
Create a new son relation using the appmaker tool
Export all the data
Re -import exactly the same data
And I’ve got this error
Drive Table internal error. Record not found. 0 associations imported

Do you know where I can find information about importing relation, on this page https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export  nothing about relation

Thanks
Stéphane